# Android-How to Draw a Alphabets by using certain Path?

Tags: android, path, draw, using

I want to draw a Alphabets[enter link description here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rafa.abc_touch_lite&feature=search_result) A to Z one by one. first i want to write 'A' in a particular path if it is correct, then it wants to move to 'B'.. All this should connect with points for example the following link shows how i expecting the same..

Answer (score 0):

you can draw to the canvas in the onDraw method of the view class.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631700/how-to-draw-something-with-your-finger-in-an-android-app-and-save-it-to-the and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703581/how-to-make-canvas-draw-area-transparent-in-android

Comment: no, OMAK actually what i need is. am trying to draw a line along two points by using particular path..